# What is this umbrella icon in Jobs supposed to represent?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Very basic question about iconography. I have no idea what the umbrella icon is supposed to represent. Worse, the tooltip is the exact same as the text beside it; in my mind, the tooltip should show what the icon means.

[image: umbrella icon]

I don't know if it's supposed to represent paid time off, or sick days, or what. Should the tooltip show the icon's meaning instead of the text value?

Comment: I think that's a beach umbrella/parasol, for holidays.

Comment: You get unlimited umbrellas for your walk home in case it rains.

Comment: Seriously though, I would treat any company that promises "unlimited holidays" with a *lot* of suspicion because it likely means you're never really on holidays.

Comment: It also means when you leave, they owe you nothing for 'unused vacation' because you never had any vacation to begin with.

Comment: @Pekka웃 you joke, but I've taken work umbrellas home at least once... it's a pretty legit perk!

Comment: Additionally, no full stop on the first two lines but one on the third one bothers me.

Comment: @n00b Or, they owe you unlimited?

Comment: Is there a _remote_ possibility that the icon refers to _unlimited_ coolers/ smoothies?

Comment: The job is offered by Umbrella Corporation, probably in Raccoon City.  On the whole, best avoided:)

Comment: "Should the tooltip show the icon's meaning instead of the text value?" Yes, there should definitely be a tooltip for that.

Comment: I believe companies are free to use any of the available icons in any meaning they want to. There aren’t exacty meanings attached to the icons because company benefits are usually very different. So if you cannot tell what *“(umbrella) unlimited”* means then it’s the fault of the company for not clarifying it. For example, I’ve seen companies use an explicit “Unlimited vacation days” or something there which shows how it should be done.

Comment: @poke Yeah I agree, but having appropriate tooltips for the icons to show what they actually mean would clear things up right away in all cases, instead of having companies clarify (or not) what it's supposed to mean.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The umbrella represents **vacation**.  In the image you posted it appears the company has an "unlimited" vacation policy - this usually translates to "you will be on call 24/7".

In any event, I agree with you, its a bit misleading, maybe the tooltip should just say "vacation".  Here is an example of a company that uses it as well:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/centah

In this case this company gives out a "vacation package" what that entails you will probably never know until you ask or are hired.

Comment: Hmm...do I want "unlimited" vacation, or a "package"? Decisions, decisions!

Comment: When I see unlimited I know there is something tied to it.  It generally means you will not enjoy your vacation as you have this feeling inside that someone is in need of you.  You also get no pay instead of time off when you want it and to add on to that when you quit or are terminated you are given no balance - since you never in fact had one.  If it's too good to be true it's probably not true.

Comment: I also worked at a place with unlimited vacation and it made me feel like I shouldn't take vacation or that I was taking too much. It just gave me a nervous feeling. Give me an amount. That way I have no bad feelings when I use all my time and perhaps I get some extra money if I don't.

Comment: @AtheistP3yace Exactly. Boundaries & time off work are important. Good employers realize that.

Comment: Maybe the icon could have a sun and some waves added so it looks like the typical beach scenario.

Comment: @bish But what if I prefer visiting the mountains? Or the countryside?